# Finding String and Reformatting Accordingly

Tags: vbscript, substring

I've been working on a VBScript that finds all files with a specific extension, .dat, searches for a specific pattern, "Date Due:\d{8}", and shifts the string around in a specific format.

I am having two problems with the below code:

- It is not reading the first line. Whenever I run the script it seems to jump immediately to the second line.
- It is only using the first pattern it finds and replaces the following patterns with the first pattern in the newly formatted manner.

I hope this makes sense, it's a very specific script, but I am hoping for some help understanding the problem here.

Below is my code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'newtext = vbLf & "Date Due:" & sub_month & sub_day & sub_year 'the text replacing Date Due:

'the purpose of this script is to format the date after Date Due:, which is currently formatted as YYYYMMDD, to MM/DD/YYYY
'example: Date Date:20180605 should be Date Due:06/05/2018
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(\nDate Due:\d{8})" 'Looking for line, Date Due: followed by 8 digits
Dim sub_str 'substring of date due, returns the 8 digits aka the date 12345678
Dim sub_month
Dim sub_day
Dim sub_year
Dim concat_full
re.Global = False
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\tgl\Desktop\TestFolder\").Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "dat" Then
        text = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
        sub_str = Mid(text, 10, 8) 'substring of the full line, outputs the 8 digit date
        sub_month = Mid(sub_str, 5, 2) 'substring of the date, outputs the 2 digit month
        sub_day = Mid(sub_str, 7, 2) 'substring of the date, outputs the 2 digit day
        sub_year = Mid(sub_str, 1, 4) 'substring of the date, outputs the four digit year
        newtext = vbLf & "Date Due:" & sub_month & "/" & sub_day & "/" & sub_year 'replaces the text pattern defined above and concatenates the substrings with slashes
        'concat_full = (sub_month & sub_day & sub_year)
        f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write re.Replace(text, newtext)
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT:** When changing `re.Global` to `True` it replaces each line with the one found pattern. It should be using each found pattern as it's own and not the first one it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regular expression more specific and use capturing groups for extracting the relevant submatches:

```
re.Pattern = "(\nDate Due:)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})"
```

then replace the matches like this:

```
re.Replace(text, "$1$4/$3/$2")
```

`$1` through `$4` in the replacement string are backreferences to the capturing groups in the pattern (i.e. they're replaced with the respective captured substring).